# Can you make hovered state in Firebug "sticky?"

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, hover

When I'm debugging a site, sometimes the hovered selectors are a little long winded and similar to other ones, is there a way to apply a kind of "sticky" state to hover rules in Firebug?

Example; I hover over a nav bar and want to copy the selector out of firebug to search in the CSS, but as soon as I move my mouse, the selector (obviously) disappears as the nav `<li>` isn't hovered anymore.

Any way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Check this answer to test hover state in chrome and firefox http://stackoverflow.com/a/20716179/1868660

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When inspecting links, Firebug shows the default CSS state, i.e. styles applied to a:link. By default, the :hover and :active styles are not shown. Fortunately, you can change the state of the link by clicking Style and choosing the appropriate option:

[image]

Comment: I know the OP answered his own question and will most likely want to keep his status points, but this was the more "Complete" answer. (I didn't quite understand his answer and thought he meant in the browser menu under one of the developer options)

Comment: FYI  if the element is using other means to control hover/active/focus, ie with Javascript, this Firebug method won't work. For example, a jquery plugin that's listening for clicks on an element and then dynamically changing CSS classes on the element. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 56):

For what I wanted, there's an option for it in the `Style` dropdown above the CSS styles for the element. Just click the dropdown, and select `:active` or `:hover` and it keeps the styles for the selected and hovered element :)

Comment: My life... it has improved dramatically, 3 years and I just assumed it was not possible.

Comment: For years, I've used weird right-clicks and tried to glitch out elements on - why oh why didn't I think to check the Style menu!

Comment: and its still a useful answer :)

Comment: you are awesome! thank you for this q/a :) helped me out alot

Comment: this improved my programming career dramatically,!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! no words can express my motion now!

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes items are not affected by the ":hover" state but by a mouseover in jQuery or similar, in that case you can manualy trigger the event (or force the event) in the console tab by writing:

```
$('#a-random-selector').mouseover()
```

Hope it helps, I came here looking for this answer but had to figure it out myself

Comment: that's awesome.  Can you make it *stay* in that state then?  Like, turn off mouseover events from there?  Cuz i'm tryna adjust values and the mouseover state just goes away on me.

Comment: In case you want to prevent the state you would have to overwrite the event listener, you would have to redifine what that particular element does when that event triggers. I would recomend you too look on the source where the event is defined and erease it over there... but some pages just have a lot of code to do it.

Comment: I wound up using the dual inspector aproach (ff built in and firebug) and also:  .unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); after using your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Chrome inspector, and trigger :active :visited state etc.. on the element under styles.

[image]

Comment: Debugging Firefox-specific issues requires using a Firefox inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Open both firebug and web developer->Inspector. In the Inspector window, locate the code line where the hover starts, right click the mouse and choose the :hover. Then the hover state will stay, you can do whatever you want in firebug.