# Inspecting Hover-state in Firebug or Chrome DevTools

Tags: html, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I've got an HTML element that has a CSS hover-state.  There's a bug with the margin or padding on hover and every time I mouseover, the contents of the element slide a little, its annoying.

I'd like to debug using FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools, but a common problem I've had with these tools is that after I select the element from Firebug/devtools I obviously need to move the mouse back to the dev tools and the hover state is no longer enabled.

How do I inspect/debug an HTML element using these tools with the element in its hover state?

Comment: [For firebug hover and active state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105102/can-you-make-hovered-state-in-firebug-sticky)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome Dev Tools has a built-in :hover state selector in the Elements > Styles panel. You can toggle other pseudo-classes (like :active) there as well.

[image]

Comment: Also in Firefox, if you want to debug the DOM instead of the CSS, you'll have to : 
1) press F12 to open the inspector
2) select the Debugger tab
3) hover the element you want to inspect while in the :hover state
4) press F8 to pause the debugger
5) select the DOM Inspector tab
Everything stops while in pause mode, JS, DOM refresh, CSS states, but CSS animations.
The most important is to be in the debugger tab while pressing F8.

Answer (score 6):

**For testing [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp%E2%80%8E) states in [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)**

[image]

**For testing [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp%E2%80%8E) state in [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/%E2%80%8E) (You need [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) add on)**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a screen shot for firebug & those not sharp enough to see agriboz's comment (like me)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now you can see both the pseudo-class style rules and force them on elements.

To see the rules like :hover in the Styles pane click the small dotted box button in the top right.

To force an element into :hover state, right click the element.

Alternatively, you can use Event Listener Breakpoints sidebar pane in the Scripts panel and select to pause in mouseover handlers.