# Get HTML code after mouseover in firebug

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

There is an HTML object that changes after mouseover. I need to inspect the changes and copy it's code, but with firebug I cannot do that (the mouse can be only in one place).

Is it possible to freeze the html while the mouse is on an object and then check the changes in firebug?

Note that, it is not the HTML attribute that changes, it is the content that changes. Another `div` is added after mouseover. So, it cannot be monitored by Style tab. For example in this link: http://demo.virtuemart.net/index.php/2012-01-13-09-33-20/product-details-layout what happens when mouse is over the product image?

Comment: I solved the problem by copying with keyboard while mouse is on the object, is there any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you make hovered state in Firebug "sticky?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105102/can-you-make-hovered-state-in-firebug-sticky)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I mentioned the differnce in one of the answers

Comment: Can you put an example of your code or some clarification then since we can't read it from your question.

Comment: For example in this link: http://demo.virtuemart.net/index.php/2012-01-13-09-33-20/product-details-layout what happens when mouse is over the main product image?

Comment: don't use firebug anymore as it demands high resources on your system. use the default firefox development tools or chrome which has (in my eyes) the best and most advanced developing tools. also consider to accept an answer, but not simply anyone!

Comment: please consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

actually i dont have firebug .. but chrome inspector can work for you.. i hope it should be available in firebug also.. check the image

[image: Check Image]

so you can try this one also..

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not the style that changes. The content changes which is not seen in the Style tab.

Comment: it doesn't matter what changes taking place i mean text OR css.. to fire the **mouseoever** event use that.. if mouseover fired it will do whatever operation u have attached on mouseover..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Ty221 I don't need any clarification from author.. he asked me that mouseover changing the text, so i cleared him. thats it,,

Comment: @DeepakSharma For example in this link: http://demo.virtuemart.net/index.php/2012-01-13-09-33-20/product-details-layout what happens when mouse is over the product image? can you copy it?

Comment: oh so now i got you.. u mean you want to call the jquery method?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes that's right. (This question of yours'd better to be  as a comment on my question.

Comment: well let me tell you if you want to work on jquery then thats completely different from firebug.. firebug is for css, for jquery we have **firequery**. to debug jquery you have to use that extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the script execution when the HTML is changed using the [*Break On Child Addition or Removal*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Context_Menu) option inside the context menu of the *HTML* panel.

To use this option you need to enable the *Script* panel first and reload the page.

**Example:**

At the page you mentioned just right-click on the `<body>` tag and choose the *Break On Child Addition or Removal* option. Then hover the product image. Doing so the script execution will stop and you'll be able to inspect the HTML for the loupe by clicking on the node inside the break notification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome you can press F8 while having the developer tools opened.
F8 pauses on next script execution. So if you hover, then press F8, then move your mouse a bit inside the element, you will be able to rightclick -> inspect it.

Answer (score -1):

In Firebug Addon you can make the state permanent with the dropdown-menu at the Style tab.

[image: Hover state in Firefox Firebug]
*https://i.stack.imgur.com/oegwD.png*

If you want to change the content of an element, you can by editing the HTML directly.

[image: Edit HTML]
*https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTTyo.png*