# How can I keep the hovered menu item open so I can edit it's style with firebug?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I click on the firebug icon and then I hover over a menu item in order to check it's css on firebug css editor

[image]

Then I hover over the style editor in order to changed something their and because the menu closes the css loses it's focus

[image]

How can I keep the hovered menu open so I can edit it's style with firebug?

Comment: find class for that sub menu and remove display:none

Comment: Isn't there a better way? A tool on firebug to stop - freeze the menu there?

Comment: If you open Firebug then on right side under style tab you can remove the desire property. this is what  @PradeepPansari already mentioned.

Comment: If I move the cursor to edit the style the menu wraps up and changes the css style.

Comment: when you select the submenu you can directly see the related CSS there.

Comment: might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105102/can-you-make-hovered-state-in-firebug-sticky?rq=1

Comment: @PradeepPansari if I remove the display:none, all menus open up which frustrates.

Comment: then you can apply style display:block on that element in style panel of right side of browser..

Comment: @KheemaPandey, good one, but for some reason the menu will not open even if I check the :hover :active and :focus. It does mark the menu Item with it's borders but the menu will not open for edit.

Comment: Anyway I found out that javascript is manipulating the css. For now I fixed the code directly from the js file. But this is third party code, so it would not be easy for other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases how such hover menus are displayed, which need to be handled differently

1. **Via CSS**
   This means the menus are displayed using the `:hover` pseudo-class. In this case you can keep the menu displayed by selecting the element reacting to the hovering within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) and then choosing the *:hover* option within the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel)'s options.
2. **Via JavaScript**
   This means the menus are displayed via some JavaScript event like `mouseover` or `click`. To be able to inspect the menus and change their styles, you need to stop the script execution as soon as a menu is hovered. If a class is added or the `display` CSS property is changed on the inline style a the menu element when it's hovered, you can achieve this by right-clicking one of the menu elements within the *HTML* panel and choosing *Break On Attribute Change* from the context menu and then hovering the menu within the page. Then the script execution will be stopped and you'll be able to switch back to the HTML panel to inspect and edit the styles.
   *Note: The [Script panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) must be enabled for this to work.*
   Instead of using the *Break On Attribute Change* option, which only works for a single HTML element, the general Break On Mutate function ( [image: Break On Mutate button] ) may also work for this purpose.